# How do I update a column only if a different column's value is false, null or doesn't match the incoming value and the incoming value is set to true?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In my table I have two columns

```
ClosedDate DateTime null
IsClosed bit null
```

If the incoming value of @IsClosed is true and the current value of `IsClosed` either null or false then I would like to update the value of `ClosedDate` to `GetDate()` like this

```
ClosedDate = GETDATE()
```

Here is what I have tried but it is not working.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].someProcedure
@IsClosed   bit,
Update dbo.Foo
SET
//Other fields to be set 
ClosedDate = CASE WHEN IsClosed = 0 OR IsClosed = NULL AND IsClosed <> @IsClosed THEN GETDATE() END,
    IsClosed = @IsClosed
WHERE myId = @myId
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you really using Sql Server 2008? It's been end of life for several years now, meaning it no longer gets any patches... **not even critical security updates**. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using that version, especially when there are free editions of more recent versions available. Upgrading this server is job #1.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn no sql-server-2012 I updated it

Comment: Well that's a little better. You have about 8 months to upgrade before you're in the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `CloseDate` to itself if it must not change, otherwise it will be set to NULL.

```sql
UPDATE dbo.Foo
SET
    ClosedDate = CASE WHEN ISNULL(IsClosed, 0) = 0 AND IsClosed <> @IsClosed
                 THEN GETDATE()
                 ELSE ClosedDate
                 END,
    IsClosed = @IsClosed
WHERE myId = @myId
```

Note, if you were setting only one column, or if both columns must be either updated or not updated together, you would simply add all the conditions to the WHERE-clause.

```sql
UPDATE dbo.Foo
SET
    ClosedDate = GETDATE()
    IsClosed = @IsClosed
WHERE
    myId = @myId AND
    ISNULL(IsClosed, 0) = 0 AND
    IsClosed <> @IsClosed
```

Also, do not test `IsClosed = 0 OR IsClosed = NULL`. This will not work as expected, because of the NULL propagation. Use `ISNULL(IsClosed, 0) = 0` instead or `COALESCE(IsClosed, 0) = 0` (I am not sure if SQL-Server 2008 already knows ISNULL).

Comment: Just for curiosity and to learn more... why `IsClosed = NULL` instead of `IsClosed is NULL`? Thank you

Comment: It must be IS NULL of course, just copy/pasted the original.

Answer (score 1):

One catch here is the case where `@IsClosed` (the input) is `0` and `IsClosed` (the column) is `NULL`. The existing `@IsClosed <> IsClosed` can have unexpected results.

This should do what you need:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].someProcedure
@IsClosed   bit, @MyId int
AS
Update dbo.Foo
SET
    ClosedDate = current_timestamp
    IsClosed = @IsClosed
WHERE myId = @myId AND COALESCE(IsCosed,0) = 0 and @IsClosed = 1
```